# Comparing two groups with multiple variables

Tags: r, statistics

I'm trying to compare the means between two groups (High vs Low density) from multiple variables (Behavior). I am trying to test the hypothesis that the total duration of an activity does not change when density changes.

I've tried several t.tests and `ANOVAS` in R, but I think my statistical knowledge mixed with the coding in Rstudio is preventing me to see exactly what I am supposed to add in each line of code.

```
    Who      Activity Duration Visitor_Density
1    Ch    Stationary       14            High
2    Co    Stationary       18            Low
3    Co   Interaction        2            Low
4    R    Stationary        6            High
5    Ch   Interaction        1            High
6    J       Display       10            High
7    Ch   Interaction        6            High
```

```
t.test(chimp2$Visitor_Density == "High", chimp2$Visitor_Density == "Low", mu=0, paired = TRUE, conf.level = 0.95)
```

Output:

```
Paired t-test

data:  chimp2$Visitor_Density == "High" and chimp2$Visitor_Density == "Low"
t = 3.9875, df = 1177, p-value = 7.09e-05
alternative hypothesis: true difference in means is not equal to 0
95 percent confidence interval:
 0.05864408 0.17225575
sample estimates:
mean of the differences 
              0.1154499
```

It looks to me like the above code is wrong, at least like I am not taking into account the different activities at all. Am I supposed to be using `ANOVA` for this? Any help will be much appreciated!

Comment: Get  in the habit of running *little pieces* of code. For example, run `chimp2$Visitor_Density == "High"` by itself. Is it what you think it is? You say you want "to compare the means between two groups", but note that you never told us, nor did you tell R, the mean of *what*? That should be another red flag.

Comment: I think what you want is to compare the means *of the duration variable*. One good way to subset the Duration values when the density is High is this:  `chimp2$Duration[chimp2$Visitor_Density == "High"]`. Use everything I've said, and see if you can do figure out the next steps.

Comment: Thank you so much for pointing these things out. I'm not sure why I completely forgot about extracting [] being a thing.

`t.test(chimp2$Duration[chimp$Visitor_Density == "High" & chimp2$Activity == "Stationary"], chimp$Duration[chimp2$Visitor_Density == "Low" & chimp2$Activity == "Stationary"], mu=0, paired = FALSE, conf.level = 0.95)` seems to be working just fine now!

Comment: Hi Sofie, you can also run it like this:

t.test(Duration ~ Visitor_Density,data=chimp2,mu=0, paired = TRUE, conf.level = 0.95)